# Scrolling down in custom ListView makes the Item's Spinner empty

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter and custom items. These items contain multiple View-element, including a Spinner. This Spinner's ArrayAdapter is set like so:

```
// Method to set or update the Tags in the Spinner
public void updateTagsSpinner(MyHolder h, Spinner sp){
    if(h != null && h.orderedProductItem != null){
        // If the given Spinner null, it means we change the OrderedProductItem's Spinner
        // Is the given Spinner not null, it means we change the Manage Tag's PopupWindow's Spinner
        if(sp == null)
            sp = h.spTags;

        // We know it's an ArrayAdapter<String> so we just ignore the 
        // "Unchecked cast from SpinnerAdapter to ArrayAdapter<String>" warning
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<String> spAdapt = (ArrayAdapter<String>) sp.getAdapter();
        ArrayList<String> tagStrings = Controller.getInstance().getAllTagsWithOrderedProductItem(h.orderedProductItem));
        if(tagStrings != null && tagStrings.size() > 0){
            if(spAdapt == null){
                spAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChecklistActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tagStrings);
                spAdapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // ArrayAdapter's setNotifyOnChange is true by default,
                // but I set it nonetheless, just in case
                spAdapt.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                sp.setAdapter(spAdapt);
            }
            else{
                spAdapt.clear();
                spAdapt.addAll(tagStrings);
            }
        }
        sp.setSelection(h.orderedProductItem.getSelectedFilter());
    }
}
```

For some reason, every time I scroll down and then up again, my Spinners are completely empty.. And when I click on them I can't even open any Spinners anymore (including the ones that aren't empty) because of a warning:

> W/InputEventReceiver(899): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, and it's a pesky one.. That's the reason why I post question/answer as whole to help others with similar problems.

**WARNING: adapter.clear() changes the original list that has been used by the ArrayAdapter!!**

In my Controller I have a HashMap (`allTagsOfProducts`) with a `key = int productId` and a `value = ArrayList<String> productTags`. In the getAllTagsWithOrderedProductItem-method I use the following:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllTagsWithOrderedProductItem(OrderedProductItem opi){
    if(opi != null && opi.getProductId() > 0){
        // Check if a new Tag has been added / removed
        if(getProductById(opi.getProductId()).getTagsHasChanged()){
            ArrayList<String> newProductTags = new ArrayList<String>();

            ... // Do some stuff to fill the newProductTags-List

            // Replace the previously saved Tags of this Products with this updated one
            allTagsOfProduct.put(opi.getProductId(), newProductTags);
            // Set the boolean on false
            getProductById(opi.getProductId()).setTagsHasChanged(false);
            // And return this update list
            return newProductTags;
        }
        // If nothing is added / removed, just return the list we already saved
        else
            return allTagsOfProduct.get(opi.getProductId());
    }
    // If the given OrderedProductItem is null return an empty list
    else
        return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

When I debugged this I found out that when I went into the else to the `return allTagsOfProduct.get(opi.getProductId());` the first time, everything works fine, and when I went here again, the saved ArrayList inside the HashMap was empty (`[]`).. The only reason I could think of was the `.clear()` method of the ArrayAdapter. So instead I had to use a new ArrayList without the reference to the ArrayList in my Controller's HashMap.

**TL;DR:** The line `ArrayList<String> tagStrings = Controller.getInstance().getAllTagsWithOrderedProductItem(h.orderedProductItem));` in my question post is replaced with:

```
// We create a new ArrayList here, since spAdapt.clear() changes the original list
// all the way into the Controller's HashMap.. You gotta love the Java references.. >.>
ArrayList<String> tagStrings = new ArrayList<String>(
    Controller.getInstance().getAllTagsWithOrderedProductItem(h.orderedProductItem));
```

PS: The reason why I also couldn't open the non-empty Spinners anymore and it gave me the Warning is because of custom ArrayAdapter's (my ListView's in this case) getView() recycling principle. [Click this link for more information of how ListView's getView() recycling works.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/1682559) It re-uses the Item's Spinner for another Item. So even though this new Item's Spinner is filled correctly with the other Item's ArrayList/ArrayAdapter, the Input-EventHandler isn't reset, so I still get this Warning for the non-empty Spinners in the recycling ListView-Item.